How can I have a cumulative total from a table that changes daily?
I have a daily schedule of when people get breaks. I would like to capture that data in a second table. The Daily table is changed daily but I would like the information to be captured and added to the 'cumulative' table so I have a record of how many times each person had a specific block as a break. The actual table has other fomulas and conditional formatting so the copy and paste special 'add' didn't work.
From the first table I only want to count as a break, when the person's name appears. If it says "On-call" I don't count it as a break. I've created a sample showing how it would look on day one and how I would like it to look on Day 2.
As a bonus the cells in blue I would like to be able to additionally capture if 3 specific blocks were given in a row.
This is for work and we are not allowed to enable macros.
Any help appreciated.
Sample Tables

Please edit your question and provide a workable data sample. The link to your OneDrive for Business file does not work.

Each day, take the sums and put them in a new table, with a column for date.
